# Can I run PHP5 and Passenger at the same time?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a webserver running apache with PHP5. I want to deploy rails applications on my webserver as well. I know how to set it all up but I came across an entry on ubuntu stating the following:

```
WARNING: libapache2-mod-passenger installation uninstalls libapache2-mod-php5 and php5
```

Does this mean I can't install mod_rails (Phusion Passenger) alongside with mod_php (PHP5) or is that just an outdated entry?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails#Configure_Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they run fine together:) You shouldn't have any problems. Just use VirtualHosts to define what hostnames/ports lead where.

I've got an Ubuntu 10.4 running PHP5 and Passenger on Apache2:)